# How to calculate time difference in perl using POSIX module?

Tags: perl, time, posix

I am new to perl scripting. I have a need where in I require to find the difference of two dates in the Days/Hrs/minutes/seconds, **provided I just have POSIX module**  ( I can't use Time::Piece or DateTime or... module)

Like,

```
$date1 = Tue Nov 30 10:53:38 2021;
$date2 = Fri Dec 10 02:12:25 2021;
```

$output = $date2 - $date1 :: **here $output should be 09 days, 3hrs, 19 mins, 47 secs.**

Can you please tell me how do we achieve this: Parsing, calculation?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: My system doesn't have this module, and I can't update it as it is a shared system, and personal updates are not allowed.

Comment: v5.8.8 is the version of perl, and I can't update.

Comment: Perl 5.8.8 is almost **16 years** old. That's so ancient it's outright dangerous to use considering all the bugfixes alone since then.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. But couldn't do anything about it for now. Can you help on the query with the mentioned conditions?

Comment: How do you get these timestamps into your program? I mean where does `Tue Nov 30 10:53:38 2021` come from?  In order to do what you ask those strings need be parsed into date-time components, then you can use some simple functions to get them as seconds-since-epoch which you can subtract, then calucalte days etc from it. It's a bit of work and things may be missing there but it's doable. But, perhaps you can read date-times into your program in a  way that makes it all easier, to start with.

Comment: Do you have examples of the actual date values you have to compare?  And why only use `POSIX`?  Why can't you use the other core modules?  This question seems oddly contrived.

Answer (score 3):

Algorithm to a solution of the problem can be achieved with [POSIX::mktime](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX) function.

Input dates require some 'massaging' to bring provided dates to expected representation by `mktime` function what is achieved by `date2epoch` function which returns representation of the date in seconds.

Once dates was converted to seconds it is a matter of trivial computation to obtain time difference represented in days/hours/minutes/seconds.

Note #1: It is assumed that dates obtained in same timezone.

Note #2: OP's date difference computation is [incorrect](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=11&d1=30&y1=2021&m2=12&d2=10&y2=2021&h1=10&i1=53&s1=38&h2=02&i2=12&s2=25)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use POSIX;

my $date1 = 'Tue Nov 30 10:53:38 2021';
my $date2 = 'Fri Dec 10 02:12:25 2021';

my $diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);

printf "Date difference: %02d days %02d hours %02d min %02d sec\n",
       $diff->@{qw/days hours min sec/};

sub date_diff {
    my $date1 = shift;
    my $date2 = shift;

    my $diff;
    my $sec_diff = date2epoch($date2) - date2epoch($date1);

    $diff->{sec}   = $sec_diff % 60;
    $diff->{min}   = ($sec_diff % 3600 - $diff->{sec} ) / 60;
    $diff->{hours} = $sec_diff / 3600 % 24;
    $diff->{days}  = int( $sec_diff / ( 24 * 3600 ) );

    return $diff;
}

sub date2epoch {
    my $str_date = shift;

    my($months,$date,$epoch);
    
    $months->@{qw/Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec/} = (0..11);

    $date->@{qw/week_day month month_day time year/} = split(' ', $str_date);
    $date->@{qw/hour min sec/} = split(':', $date->{time});
    
    $date->{month} = $months->{ $date->{month} };
    $date->{year} -= 1900;
    
    $epoch = POSIX::mktime( $date->@{qw/sec min hour month_day month year/} );
    
    return $epoch;
}
```

Output

```
Date difference: 09 days 15 hours 18 min 47 sec
```